# Change a line in a file containing a specific String in C#

Tags: c#

ive got a problem: i want to find a line containing a certain string, but i only know how to replace the string in the file or all the lines, i know the command "string.Contains", but it doesnt seem to work properly as i use it: i tried to use "if (data.contains(string))", but then it still changes all the lines to that string. heres my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string replaceText = "peter";
    string withText = "Gilbert";
    using (System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\G\Documents\test.txt"))
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\G\Documents\test.txt" + ".tmp"))
        {

            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string data = streamReader.ReadLine();
                data = data.Replace(replaceText, withText);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }

    }
    using (System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\G\Documents\test.txt" + ".tmp"))
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\G\Documents\test.txt"))
        {

            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string data = streamReader.ReadLine();
                data = data.Replace(replaceText, withText);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(data);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? just find a string in a txt file and then what?

Comment: Like @StanR. said, please explain, in detail, what you are trying to do.Until then, you should consider writing out your text file content to a StringBuilder and then work with that StringBuilder object to get the text exactly how you want it, then write out the SB object content to your text file (or a new text file). Keep in mind that your code is creating many string objects in your while statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open("file", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(rdr);
String[] flines = rdr.ReadToEnd().Split(new String[]{"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
rdr.Close();
stream = File.Create("file");
StreamWriter wtr = new StreamWriter(stream);
foreach(String str in flines)
{
    wtr.WriteLine(str.Replace(replaceTxt, newText));
}
wtr.Close();
```

Of course you could put logic in the loop the either change or not change the string written based on whatever criterion you like.